# C scanf function returns too much elements

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following (code [here](https://ideone.com/TADiQi)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(char* m, int* a, int c){
    printf("%s (%d els.)\n", m, c);
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");       
}

int main(void) {
    int c = 0;
    int a[50];
    
    while(scanf("%d", &a[c++]) == 1);
    
    print("Init array: ", a, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Then having the input `5 6 2 1 8 8 1`, I have following output:

```
Init array:  (8 els.)
5 6 2 1 8 8 1 0
```

Where from is the last `0`?

Comment: When `scanf` returns 0 you still increment `c`.

Comment: Next time, rather than a "one liner".. break up your lines and use the debugger to tell you what happened.  In this case, you would have needed to assign a variable to the result of scanf before comparing it to 1.

Comment: @WhozCraig, this is not **printF**

Comment: @Serge derp. thx. Regarding your problem, `while (c < 50 && scanf("%d", a+c) == 1 ) ++c;` seems about right. Its clearer to read and understand for me, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `c++` in `&a[c++]` incremented `c` one last time, so after you entered `n` elements, `c == n + 1`. This is why your code says `(8 els.)` when you entered 7 elements. `a[c - 1] == a[7]` happened to be zero.

Comment: how to fix elegantly

Comment: You could simply decrement `c` after the loop if `c != 0`

Comment: @ForceBru: `c` is guaranteed to have been incremented once, so I think the decrement could be made unconditional. Alternatively, initialize `c` to `-1`, and have the loop do `&a[++c]` so the increment always brings you to, not past, the index to write (works because `c` is signed, so don't switch to `size_t` or something).

Comment: @ShadowRanger, actually yes, `c++` will be executed anyway, so it'll always be positive

Comment: Simpler: rewrite the loop `while(scanf("%d", &a[c++]) == 1);` as `while(scanf("%d", &a[c]) == 1) c++;` — so `c` is only incremented when it is used successfully.  Better: `while (c < 50 && scanf("%d", &a[c]) == 1) c++;` to avoid overflows of the array.

Comment: @Serge Go with [`while (c < 50 && scanf("%d", &a[c]) == 1) c++;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64434069/c-scanf-function-returns-too-much-elements#comment113935667_64434095).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, what if there is more than 50 scans? maybe corrupt the memory?

Comment: @Serge: better - `while(c < (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])) && scanf("%d", &a[c]) == 1) c++;`

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica, why it's better?

Comment: @Serge: If `a`'s size changes, the `sizeof` approach ensures you'll still adhere to its bounds (as long as it remain a true array, not a pointer); a hard-coded `50` would need to modified to match.